# Statistical Significance of three distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, anova, variance, t-test

Within each of the treatment classes below, I have calculated the subgroup as a percentage in each.  For example, Treatment A; Subgroup: <29,999 I would divide 769 by the sum of the Person_IDs for Subgroup A (769+1189+1977+2509+2744+1197).  This would be 7.4% of the total.

I've done this for each Class and now I want to know if the differences I am seeing between groups are statistically significant.  Not being an expert statistician, I do not know what test I should use to make that determination.  Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

[image: Treatment Data]

Comment: Google for ANOVA

Comment: Yes, they will be significant: the large counts and even larger variations among them make this obvious.  You might find it more useful to explore specifically *how* these three distributions differ.  Why not begin by plotting them?

Comment: Thanks, whuber.  I felt like I was over thinking this thing.  Just to recap, the large sample sizes make testing for significance irrelevant because they should be representative?  Also, I have already plotted them and I was seeing differences I thought could be insignificant, but I believe I see your logic.  Am I correct?

Comment: Tim, the ANOVA I did on this data gave me an extremely low p-value.

Answer (score 0):

Given that subgroup is a categorical variable and you want to compare differences in the frequency of subgroup "<29,999" among classes, I would divide subgroup into a binary variable (subgroup "<29,999" coded as 1 for every person in this group, and as 0 for any other subgroup) and then fit a generalized linear model with binomial distribution and the logit as link function to the data. You can enter subgroup as dependent and the treatment class variable as categorical indpendent variable into the model. In R this would look like: M <- glm(formula = subgroup ~ as.factor(treatment), family = binomial(link='logit')). The estimated coefficients for group differences, shown in the model output (summary(M)) also provide p-values, e.g,  given that class A is coded as 0, class B as 1, and class C as 2, the result will show you the difference in the logit (log odds) of being in subgroup "<29,999" for class B versus class A, and class C versus class A. By exponentiating the respective estimated coefficient you can also calculate the odds ratios, which give you an estimate on how many times the chance of being in subgroup "<29,999" is higher/lower for class B compared to class A. Hope this is helpful. Cheers.